# Basic test framework in Python

Tags: python

I am new to Python and I was asked to write script to do some test, what Python module can I start with? unittest?

example tests would be:

```
if not host_is_pingable():
     print "Unable to ping"
     sys.exit()
if not able_to_ssh():
     print "Unable to ssh into the host"
     sys.exit()
if not mounts_are_ok():
     print "Missing mounts"
     sys.exit()
if not misc_test():
     print "some error"
     sys.exit()
```

Comment: Those don't look like unit tests. They look like precondition checks. What exactly do you mean by "tests"?

Comment: If you want to do purely string based tests you can use doctests https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html

Comment: Thanks surfer190, this helps too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do tests, often it depends on what framework you use. But, just assuming that you want some form of a formal test framework, you can use pytest.

**Step 1,** install pytest

```
$ pip install pytest
```

**Step 2,** Format your code. You will test your output according to the return of the function.

```
def host_is_pingable(x):
    #Do your verification logic here... putting the result in a string valid
    return valid
```

**Step 3,** Now write the tests

```
def test_answer():
    assert host_is_pingable(ip_address) != "some error"
```

Step 4, run the tests

```
$ py.test
```

This is not a unittest, but a boilerplate test framework.

If you want to do unittests, there is a great guide to it here: http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/python/2004/12/02/tdd_pyunit.html

**Update 2019**

The unittest introductory guide link is now dead but you can find it archived at WayBackMachine here https://web.archive.org/web/20180121231649/http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/python/2004/12/02/tdd_pyunit.html